# forward function calls to all list items

Tags: java, delegates

I want to create a class, that simply forwards a function call to each item in the list it contains. Callable functions are declared by an interface
So for example (pseudo-code):

```
ListObjectForwarder<InterfaceFoo> interfaceFooForwarder;
interfaceFooForwarder.foo1(3,4);
```

should result in the following code:

```
foreach object in list
    object.foo1(3,4);
```

and the call

```
interfaceFooForwarder.foo2("hello");
```

should result in

```
foreach object in list
    object.foo2("hello");
```

So as you see: the pattern for how the calls should turn out is always a foreach loop with that very same call and parameter. Forwardable calls are restricted by a given Interface (here InterfaceFoo - or eg.InterfaceBar)

One important detail is, that the function caller should not be able to make a difference whether he is calling one object, that directly implements the interface or a group/list of objects as in this example.

How could I do something like that in Java?
I guess I would need delegates(?), but I can't figure out how I would apply them here correctly.

> edit:
>
> I would not want to implement foo1 and foo2 separately. The goal is to tell the machine once "whatever function call comes, do it on all elements in the list"
>
> Also, I'll assume, that every function returns a void

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understood correctly your question:

```
class yourList<T>{

    List<T> list = new LinkedList<>();

    void generic(String methodName, Object...args){
        for (Object obj: list) {
            try {

                Class<?>[] classes = new Class<?>[args.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
                    classes[i] = args[i].getClass();
                }
                Method mtd = obj.getClass().getMethod(methodName, classes);
                mtd.invoke(obj, args);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and of course you have to add constructor, helper methods to add elements etc.

Hope this help as a starting point

Comment: @TheTrowser make sense?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain it good enough. I updated the question: I would not want to implement foo1 and foo2 specifically. Rather something similar to a generic function call with a generic body